# jQuery AJAX response object logs keys on console as undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

**Accepted answer by Rohan Kumar:**

Changed $.post() into

```
$.post("monitor/loadEVents", function(data){
    if(data && data.response){                    // (didn't even have to change this for it to work, but I like this condition more than my own one)
        console.log('Wow, it works.');
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
},'json');                 // put the third parameter as json
```

**Original question below:**

I'm trying jQuery AJAX for the first time in Zend Framework 2 (I've never worked with AJAX before at all). That being said, I don't have very extensive experience in working with JSON yet either, so please forgive me for rookie mistakes ;)

In my js file I'm calling a function in my controller to return a JSON object. My problem is that when I log 'data' to the console, it logs the structure of it just fine, but when I try to do something with the keys of 'data', their values come back as undefined.

This is where I call the function:

```
$('#loadmore').on('click', function(event){
    $.post("monitor/loadEVents", function(data){
        if(data.response == true){
            console.log('Wow, it works.');       // Want this condition met, but it never is.
        } else {
            console.log(data);                   // so it logs data
        }
    })
});
```

Here's the function inside my controller:

```
public function loadEventsAction(){
    $request    = $this->getRequest();
    $response   = $this->getResponse();
    if($request->isPost()){
        $events = array('a bunch' => 'of stuff');
        $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode(array('response' => true, 'events' => $events)));
    }
    return $response;
}
```

This is how it logs data:

```
{"response":true,"events":{"a bunch":"of stuff"}}
```

What do I do so I can get to the response and events keys in 'data' properly?

Comment: Is the server sending `Content-type: application/json`? If not, you need to put `dataType: 'json'` in the `$.post()` options.

Comment: @Barmar So do you mean modifying $.post() to this? *$.post("monitor/loadEVents",{
   dataType: 'json'
  },* Just tried this, but it's not working.

Comment: @Barmar, nvm, I think I did what you said wrong. Did it the way the answer said and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$.post("monitor/loadEVents", function(data){
    if(data && data.response){
        console.log('Wow, it works.');  // Want this condition met, but it never is.
    } else {
         console.log(data);       // so it logs data
    }
},'json');// put the third parameter as json
```

Read [post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)